# C++ SFINAE with CRTP, G++ compile error

Tags: c++, sfinae, crtp

I would like to know if the following code are valid.

The original intension is that, I like a base class that dispatch calls to a certain member to either derived class members if it is there or fall back to default behaviors if derived class does not have this member. Another use is that this base class can be used by itself and the `Derived` template parameter becomes a implementation policy. Anyway, the following MWE compiles and runs correctly with `clang++`, Intel, `icpc` and MSVS. However it fails with `g++` (from 4.4 to 4.6, any version I had a hand on) with the error message at the end of the question.

If I change the `call` at point (1), (2), (3) to `call_dispatch` (which was the sort of thing I did originally), `g++` does not complain anymore. I don't think it is a good practice to have the dispatch function and the caller having the same name. I was just curious if it will work, and curiously enough to try it out (I have no idea how does this idea come to me). My rationale behind this is that, at pint (1), `call` is invoked with one parameter, so the overload resolution will not match its caller, the zero parameter one. It will  not match the `SFINAE` one at point (2) either, since `D2` does not have the member, and then it shall match the one at point (3). Just as in the situation when (1)-(3) are named `call_dispatch`.

But `g++` does not agree with me and other compilers. So, is it an incorrect implementation of `g++` or the code itself is invalid? Besides the error message is really confusing. Where does the `void (B<D2>::*)()` and `&B<D2>::call` come from? Int he called the member pointer was defined as `D2`'s member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename Derived>
class B
{
    public :

    void call ()
    {
        call<Derived>(0); //----------------------------------------- (1)
    }

    private :

    template <typename D, void (D::*)()> class SFINAE {};

    template <typename D>
    void call (SFINAE<D, &D::call> *) //---------------------------- (2)
    {
        static_cast<Derived *>(this)->call();
    }

    template <typename D>
    void call (...) //--------------------------------------------- (3)
    {
        std::cout << "Call B" << std::endl;
    }
};

class D1 : public B<D1>
{
    public :

    void call ()
    {
        std::cout << "Call D1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class D2 : public B<D2> {};

int main ()
{
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    d1.call();
    d2.call();

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
foo.cpp: In member function ‘void B<Derived>::call() [with Derived = D2]’:
foo.cpp:48:13:   instantiated from here
foo.cpp:11:9: error: ‘&B<D2>::call’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘void (D2::*)()’ because it is of type ‘void (B<D2>::*)()’
foo.cpp:11:9: note: standard conversions are not allowed in this context
```

**Edit**

Though I have not fully understand what goes wrong in the above code yet. But I think there is a another way without specifically construct a SFINAE class but archive the same effect.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
class B
{
    public :

    void call ()
    {
        call_dispatch(&Derived::call);
    }

    template <typename C>
    void call_dispatch (void (C::*) ())
    {
        static_cast<Derived *>(this)->call();
    }

    void call_dispatch (void (B<Derived>::*) ())
    {
        std::cout << "Call B" << std::endl;
    }

    private :
};

class D1 : public B<D1>
{
    public :

    void call ()
    {
        std::cout << "Call D1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class D2 : public B<D2> {};

int main ()
{
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;

    d1.call();
    d2.call();

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, because `D1` and `D2` both are derived from `B`, so the expression `&Derived::call` will always be resolved. In `D1` it resolved to `&D1::call`, then the template version member is used. In `D2`, it does not have its own `call`, so `&D2::call` is resolved to `&B::call`, and thanks to
@DavidRodríguez-dribeas, who points out that now `&D2::call` has the type `B::call`, therefore the template and the non-template members equally match, but non-template is preferred. So the default call is used.

Can help me see if there is any defect in this new code?

Comment: Not an answer but a work-around: Using a separate `has_call` traits class fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I know a few ways to fix. Still I want to understand what goes wrong here

Comment: Exactly. Actually as mentioned all but gcc accept it without a warning. I usually develop with clang as it tends to be more strict than gcc and reject invalid code accepted by gcc. Now I am less sure of this

Comment: Clang++ accepts the code, I am not 100% sure which of the two is correct... The problem is that because `D2` inherits from `B<D2>`, so the expression `&D::call` is actually well formed, but *strangely* (I think this is a defect of the standard), the type is `void (B<D2>::*)()`, not `void (D2::*)()`, so it cannot be used in the template. Whether that is a *Substition Failure* or an error is a different issue.

Comment: Are you compiling in C++11 mode?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas both c++11 and 03 tried

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Another point is that simply change the name of the dispatch function, `g++` works as expected. So it does thinks it is a failure. Changing the name does not change the fact when trying to substitute the member template, it will still be resolved to `B<D2>::call`.

Comment: If you rename the dispatch function, then `B<D2>::call` is no longer defined, is it? That is, it has been renamed so it is no longer a candidate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12580/discussion-between-yan-zhou-and-david-rodriguez-dribeas)

Comment: BTW, there is an open issue (from back in 2000) regarding the type of the expression (and suggesting that it should not be `void (B<D2>::*)()` but `void (D2::*)()`... I myself agree with that issue, and believe that making that change to the standard would actually improve it (and fix other issues that cannot be handled now) at the cost of potentially breaking currently working code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does the void (B::*)() and &B::call come from?

The type of a pointer to member is not the type on which you obtained such pointer, but the type on which the member is defined.

```
struct base { int x; };
struct derived : base {};
int main() {
   std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(&derived::x), int (base::*) >::value << std::endl;
}
```

The above program prints `1`. In your case, when you use `&D::base`, the compiler finds `B<D2>::call` as a member of the base template, and that is the result of the expression: `void (B<D2>::*)()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your instantiation of `SFINAE` is expecting the function pointer template argument to be of type `void (D2::*)()`, but instead is of type `void (B<D2>::*)()` (because `call` is not overidden in `D2`, it uses the one defined in `B<D2>`).

**Edit**

It is not the instantiation of  `template <typename D>
    void call (SFINAE<D, &D::call> *)` that is failing here. There is no substitution error there. The substitution error occurs with the instantiation of `SFINAE<B<D2>, &B<D2>::call>`, of which there is no fallback instantiation, hence the error.

Comment: Since the types don't match, this is a *Substitution Failure*, is it not? So, according to the standard *Is Not An Error* and you have the whole *SFINAE*, which should discard that particular template and pick the next option, which is the one with the ellipsis. Should it not? Why not?

Comment: The quoted part only state what is a 'failure' as far as I understand. As @DavidRodríguez-dribeas said, it is not an error. If it is the only template member, then the program is illformed

Comment: Withdrawn. I had to think about it a little more, but it seems there is a level of indirection with the substitution failure.